# how to change a sprite on contact without colliders passing through each other

Tags: game-physics, unity-game-engine

Basically, I am from a SpriteKit background where contact can be established without collision necessarily. I am trying to do get the same effect in Unity2d, where I want one object's image and collider to change from a circle to rectangle when it passes through another object without them bouncing or reacting to force of collision. Please see my code below:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)    {
        if (col.collider.name == "Enemy") {

        if(circleColliderOn){

            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = rectTargetSprite;

            boxColliderOn = true;
            boxCollider.enabled = true;
            GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            circleColliderOn = false;

            Debug.Log("reached here");

        }
    }
}
```

Also in my code, the circle changes to the rectangle, but the box collider does not increase to the size of the rectangle which is bigger, it remains the same.

**UPDATE**

I changed from `OnCollisionEnter2D` to `onTriggerEnter2D` and set the TriggerOn property, but the trigger is not recognised. Not even the first log in the updated code below is displaying. I did some research on this issue and have already checked the following:

- one game object has a rigidBody2D
- `isKinematic` is disabled
- colliders for both objects are set
- ensured game object name is correct

  ```
  void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collision2D col)  {
  Debug.Log("reached here");

  if (col.collider.name == "Enemy") {
      if(circleColliderOn){

          GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = rectTargetSprite;

          boxColliderOn = true;
          boxCollider.enabled = true;
          GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().enabled = false;
          circleColliderOn = false;               
          Debug.Log("LOGGED");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Contact in Unity2D is done through `OnTriggerEnter2D` or `OnCollisionEnter2D` when the colliders intersect.

If you don't want them to react to forces then add a rigidbody2D and tick `IsKinematic`. It doesn't make much sense to want to have sprites changing on contact without using colliers.

Comment: Make your collider `IsTrigger`, and use `OnTriggerEnter2D`

Comment: @LibertyLocked I just updated the question

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson I just updated the question. Some sprites collide with others and just pass through some, that's why I don't need colliders for this case. At least each sprite collides with some other sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void OnTriggerEnter2d(Collision2D col)
```

change this to

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
```

The method name is important, has to be the same, as well as using Collider and not collision class as param.

You don't need `col.collider.name` now, so you can just change it to `col.name` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html